# Fish shell unable to render symbols properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, fish, gnome-terminal

Fish shell is not displaying symbols properly in gnome-terminal (Ubuntu 17.04).

1. Fish prompt symbol
2. Staging index status

[image: Fish prompt symbol]
[image: Staging index status]
 -

**locale output**

```
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE=en_IN
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Insufficient data. What symbol is not displayed properly? Is it in your prompt? If so please show your `fish_prompt` function. What does `locale` report? And is your terminal configured to use the same char set and encoding?

Answer (score 1):

You should set your locale to a UTF-8-containing locale (ie `en_IN.UTF-8`). Ubuntu normally does this by default, so perhaps you should run `sudo update-locale LANG=en_IN.UTF-8 LANGUAGE="en_IN:en"`.

If that still fails to work, in the GNOME Terminal profile settings, under the compatibility tab, try setting "Ambiguous-width characters" to "Wide" instead of "Narrow".

Comment: Tried running `sudo update-locale LANG=en_IN.UTF-8 LANGUAGE="en_IN:en"` and changing compatibility settings. None of them worked.